# Rails app deployment challenge, not finding database table in production.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, ruby

I'm trying to setup [PasswordPusher](https://github.com/pglombardo/PasswordPusher) as my first ruby app ever. Building and running the webrick server as instructed in README works fine.

It was only when I tried to add Apache ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse that the page load slowed down to several minutes.

So I gave mod_passenger a whirl but now it's unable to find the password table. Here's what I get in log/production.log.

```
Started GET "/" for 10.10.2.13 at Sun Jun 10 08:07:19 +0200 2012
  Processing by PasswordsController#new as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'passwords'):
  app/controllers/passwords_controller.rb:77:in `new'
  app/controllers/passwords_controller.rb:77:in `new'
```

While in log/private.log I get a lot more output so here's just a snippet but it looks to me like it's working with the database. Edit: This was actually old log output, maybe from db:create.

```
Migrating to AddUserToPassword (20120220172426)
   (0.3ms)  ALTER TABLE "passwords" ADD "user_id" integer
   (0.0ms)  PRAGMA index_list("passwords")
   (0.2ms)  CREATE INDEX "index_passwords_on_user_id" ON "passwords" ("user_id")
   (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ('20120220172426')
   (0.1ms)  select sqlite_version(*)
   (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" 
   (0.0ms)  PRAGMA index_list("passwords")
   (0.0ms)  PRAGMA index_info('index_passwords_on_user_id')
   (4.6ms)  PRAGMA index_list("rails_admin_histories")
   (0.0ms)  PRAGMA index_info('index_rails_admin_histories')
   (0.0ms)  PRAGMA index_list("users")
   (4.8ms)  PRAGMA index_info('index_users_on_unlock_token')
   (0.0ms)  PRAGMA index_info('index_users_on_reset_password_token')
   (0.0ms)  PRAGMA index_info('index_users_on_email')
   (0.0ms)  PRAGMA index_list("views")
```

In my vhost I have it set to use RailsEnv private.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#  ProxyPreserveHost on
#
#  ProxyPass / http://10.220.100.209:180/
#  ProxyPassReverse / http://10.220.100.209:180/
  DocumentRoot /var/www/pwpusher/public
  <Directory /var/www/pwpusher/public>
    allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
  RailsEnv private

  ServerName pwpush.intranet

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  LogLevel debug
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My passenger.conf in mods-enabled is default for Debian.

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr
  PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
</IfModule>
```

In the apache error.log I get something more cryptic to me.

```
[Sun Jun 10 06:25:07 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Phusion_Passenger/2.2.11 PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze9 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations
/var/www/pwpusher/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/modernizr-rails-09e9e6a92d67/lib/modernizr/rails/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
cache: [GET /] miss
[Sun Jun 10 08:07:19 2012] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 10.10.2.13] Zlib: Compressed 728 to 423 : URL /
/var/www/pwpusher/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/modernizr-rails-09e9e6a92d67/lib/modernizr/rails/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
cache: [GET /] miss
[Sun Jun 10 10:17:16 2012] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 10.10.2.13] Zlib: Compressed 728 to 423 : URL /
```

Maybe that's routine stuff. I can see the rake command create files in the relative app root db/. I have private.sqlite3, production.sqlite3 among others. And here's my config/database.yml.

```
base: &base
  adapter: sqlite3
  timeout: 5000

development:
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  <<: *base

test:
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  <<: *base

private:
  database: db/private.sqlite3
  <<: *base

production:
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  <<: *base
```

I've tried setting absolute paths in it but that did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Your configs look valid and are similar to what I'm running for Passwordpusher @ pwpush.com.

Make sure that you run the db:create/db:migrate rake tasks with the proper environment:

```
RAILS_ENV=private bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate
```

Not providing the RAILS_ENV part will cause rake to use the default which is 'development'.

To validate, make sure that db/private.sqlite3 is created and timestamped correctly in the OS.

If this still doesn't work, submit an issue here and I'll give you a hand (I'm the author of PasswordPusher): https://github.com/pglombardo/PasswordPusher/issues